# undefined is not an object (evaluating's.NativeModules.ExponentNotifications.getExponentPushTokenAsync')

Tags: react-native

I'm using from react-native to create my app. but when run app on device, this error coming:

[image: undefined is not an object]

**App.js**:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'; 
import Exponent, {Font, Components} from 'exponent';
 
import {
  NavigationProvider,
  StackNavigation,
  SharedElementOverlay
} from '@exponent/ex-navigation'; 
import stl from './components/theme';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R',
  android: 
    'Shake or press',
});
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
});
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "mobileshopping",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Hello Exponent!",
  "author": "mironcatalin@gmail.com",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@exponent/ex-navigation": "^2.0.0",
    "@exponent/vector-icons": "~2.0.3",
    "expo": "^33.0.6",
    "exponent": "~11.0.2",
    "react": "~15.3.2",
    "react-native": "0.39.0",
    "react-native-animate-number": "^0.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@exponent/vector-icons": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

When i remove the third line of App.js file, it's work perfectly. Can any one say me why this error appears?

A newbie :(

Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Exponent' project has beeen renamed to 'Expo'. This package is now named 'expo'.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/exponent

Check the link.

Comment: I added `import * as Expo from 'expo'` but this error coming: `undefined is not an object (evaluating.default.manifest.env)`